# ASP.NET session alternative to pass object between pages

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to pass an object between pages of my website. I know I can use session object for this.

Personally, I don't want to use any session or application or caching for this.

Is there any other alternative?

Please help.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: it would help if you can explain why you don't want to use session/application/cache!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to serialize the object into a hidden field and when you post to the other page deserialize the value back to an object instance. Or yet another possibility would be to persist the object to some data store and then use an id to fetch it back.

Comment: @Mahesh, in summary, you have to serialize your object and either pass it as a string OR store it in some persistent medium with associated key and pass the key. Another way w/o serialization would be to put it in a static dictionary but it would be rather unsafe equivalent of application/cache object.